# Back button and last activity

Tags: android

My app chains some activities.

if you press the back button, you go back through old activities then you suddenly quit the application !

so I need to show a message like "do you really want to exit" if it's the last activity on stack

I know how to override the back button but i can't figure how to know how many activity are in history

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // Is it the last activity on stack ? 
        // so show confirm dialog
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Does your application not have a main, root-level activity where you can assume this to be true?

Comment: As a side note - I would uninstall any app that bugs me when I try to exit it with the back button. This is a phone app, not a big desktop application.

Comment: I agree with EboMike. Hijacking the back button is not a very good idea

Comment: What they said. On a similar note: http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2010/05/when-to-include-exit-button-in-android.html

Answer (score 14):

you can achieve that using the finish() function

```
public void finish() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("do you really want to exit?");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                quit();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    public void quit() {
        super.finish();
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You needn't know how many activity are in history.You can do this way.Invoke the method of onBackPressed() when back button is clicked.Then override the method of finish() in your main activity to show confirm dialog.Because onBackPressed() method invoke activity's finish() method.When backing to the main activity,the overriding finish() method is invoked,there will show the dialog you have overrided.