# back button still closed my app

Tags: android, back-button

I try to override this method and stuck with some problem

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
          if(screenStatus >=1)
          {screenStatus=0;
              indexMenu();


          }
          if(screenStatus==0)

              {
                finish();
              }return false;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

when i press on backbutton   my app closed.. but if see on code.. there must be call function  indexMenu();
 i mean  i have menu ... press some one from menu  (start for example.. ) and have new window.. there i press on back button and i see how app return to main menu (indexMenu() ) and than closed (1 second after returning to indexMenu())

Can any tell me how to fix this ?

Regards,Peter

similar problem i found here [Back button and last activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507265/back-button-and-last-activity) 
but i don't need alertBuilder.. and not need other message on the screen.. just want to back to indexMenu() without problem.

**UPD AFTER HELP**
ok after help this code work perfectly for me :

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
         if (screenStatus>=1)
         {
            indexMenu();
            screenStatus=0;
          //  super.onBackPressed();
         }
         else if(screenStatus==0)
         {
          finish();
          super.onBackPressed();
         }
     }
```

Thanks to : **lordl** , **PKeidel**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it this way and it works fine:

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if (youWantToCloseTheApp)
            super.onBackPressed();
        else
            // Do other funny things here
    }
```

Comment: You can't always rely on this!

Answer (score 1):

Override [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) instead, and handle it there.
If you don't call super.onBackPressed(), the app won't close.